# Create columns for each month

Tags: list, column

I need to create a forecast list where users can enter the projected number of staff for each project. Rather than manually entering the columns for each month, is there an automated way of creating a single entry with different values per month?

This is what im trying to achieve:

[image: Table view]

The idea is to make it dynamic without having to manually add new months as the years go by.

Many thanks,

Owen

Answer (score 0):

The typical method would be to create a list with three columns: project, month, and projectedStaff. Adding a new estimate would just involve adding a row.

Power BI or Excel could connect to this list and do a "pivot" to output the data as you have in your example, where each month is in a different column.

Optionally, you could create a power app to simplify the process of adding rows. For example, it could simply provide three textboxes for the values, and the app could take care of creating a row for each value.